# CSMA /CD calculation for numerical

Tags: networking

I need a calculation for this problem
Suppose a new CSMA/CD protocol is designed for a 100 Mbps bus network with topology similar to 10Base2. The minimum frame length is 40 bytes. What is the maximum length of the longest cable connecting two nodes so that the collision detection mechanism still works?

Comment: Question does not show lot of effort on your behalf. This isn't my expertise but a quick Google search gives me plenty of leads and formulas.

Comment: don't know which formula to use, would appreciate if somebody could help.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if we can determine it from first principles.

For Ethernet-style collision-detection to work, the current transmitter must stay transmitting long enough for the beginning of the transmission to reach the far end of the collision domain (i.e. the far end of the coax cable, in the case of 10BASE-2), and also long enough for the resulting "jam" signal to reach all the way back to the transmitter, so that the transmitter will still be "on the line" to detect that a collision has happened.

So, in your scenario, you've got a minimum of 40 bytes * 8 bits per byte = 320 bits per transmission, minimum. You're transmitting at 100 million bits per second, which means each bit takes 10 nanoseconds to transmit, so the minimum transmission time is 3200 nanoseconds (3.2 microseconds).

So, to a first approximation, your cable needs to be short enough for signals to reach the other end AND BACK within 3.2 µsec. Assuming the speed of electrical signals in your cable is approximately equal to the speed of light in a vacuum, we can calculate that your signal can travel about 959 meters in 3.2 µsec. So your cable can only be half that length (because we have to account for the return trip), so your cable should be no longer than 479.5 meters.

This first approximation ignores things like the processing time it takes for the colliding (far end of the cable) transmitter to recognize a collision, start sending a jam signal, and for the original transmitter to recognize the jam signal. Can it really recognize a jam signal if it only arrives during the 10ns window as the last bit is being transmitted, or does it need a few more bit-times' worth of overlap in order to ensure the jam signal is detected?

It also doesn't take into account the fact that electrical signals in a copper wire probably move a little slower than light in a vacuum. It also ignores possible physical layer preambles that may make the minimum transmission length at the PHY layer a little longer than the specified 40 octet minimum at the MAC layer.